# How to open a web page on button click inside an app?

Tags: android, android-intent, onclick, html

I searched over the net, and tried most of the similar topics in stackoverflow, but couldn't solve this. That's why I'm posting a question.

I want to create a very simple android application. There is a button, and if the user clicks on that button, it should open a specific website ***inside*** that application. That's it.

I've set the settings of this example project for Android 4.1.

After writing the codes, I do ***Build / Make Project*** , and then ***Build / Build APK*** , and then install this APK in my android phone (Android 7.0).

After installing and opening the app, I press the ***CONNECT*** button, but just right then, the app disappears (goes to background); it does not open the website.

Here are my codes:

**MainActivity.java**

```
package example_company.test_2;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void goToGoogle (View view) {
        goToUrl ( "http://www.google.com/");
    }

    private void goToUrl (String url) {
        Uri uriUrl = Uri.parse(url);
        Intent launchBrowser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uriUrl);
        startActivity(launchBrowser);
    }

}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="example_company.test_2.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!" />

    <Button
        android:text="CONNECT"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:onClick="goToGoogle (MainActivity)" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="example_company.test_2">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="http" android:host="www.google.com" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

***So, what is the problem?
Am I missing something !?***

***EDIT1***

Here is the logcat errors when I press the CONNECT button, after changing the codes according to the answer from @pleft :

```
10-31 13:51:25.681 12178-12178/example_company.test_2 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                      Process: example_company.test_2, PID: 12178
                                                                      java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
                                                                          at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5646)
                                                                          at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22459)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:761)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6531)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:941)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:831)
                                                                       Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
                                                                          at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5646) 
                                                                          at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22459) 
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:761) 
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98) 
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6531) 
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:941) 
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:831) 
                                                                       Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {example_company.test_2/example_company.test_2.WebViewActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
                                                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1850)
                                                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1544)
                                                                          at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4391)
                                                                          at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityJB.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityJB.java:48)
                                                                          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:75)
                                                                          at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4335)
                                                                          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:856)
                                                                          at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4697)
                                                                          at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4665)
                                                                          at example_company.test_2.MainActivity.goToUrl(MainActivity.java:25)
                                                                          at example_company.test_2.MainActivity.goToGoogle(MainActivity.java:19)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
                                                                          at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5646) 
                                                                          at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22459) 
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:761) 
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98) 
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6531) 
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:941) 
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:831)
```

Comment: If you want to load website in your app then you have to add WebView tag in your xml and load url on that

Comment: You have 2 options to load website from your app. one is WebView and other one is ChromeTab.

Comment: Please paste ur log file

Comment: you probable want to change this : `android:onClick="goToGoogle (MainActivity)"` to `android:onClick="goToGoogle"`.

Comment: In your question I can see 2 problems you are facing. First problem is that you click the button and the app goes to background with nothing happening, so it probably crashes? if yes share the `logcat` errors. Second problem is that you wan to open a website **inside** your app, this is usually done via a `WebView`. Can you confirm, elaborate if these 2 are the problems you are facing? If yes both need solving

Comment: @pleft , yes I have these two problems. Only the app doesn't crash. it just goes to background. I can launch it again.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Update your manifest to allow internet connection

   `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`
2. Create the layout of your `webview`

**webview.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
/>
```

3. Create the `WebViewActivity` class

**WebViewActivity**

```
public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.webview);

        Intent i = getIntent();
        String url= i.getStringExtra("url");
        WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        assert url != null;
        webView.loadUrl(url);
    }
}
```

4. Update your `MainActivity.goToUrl` code to the following:

   private void goToUrl (String url) {
   Intent intent = new Intent(this, WebViewActivity.class);
   intent.putExtra("url", url);
   startActivity(intent);
   }
5. Change in your `activity_main.xml` the line:

   android:onClick="goToGoogle (MainActivity)"

to

```
android:onClick="goToGoogle"
```

6. To resolve the error in the logcat stacktrace posted in the question, the new activity must be declared in the `manifest`. So just above the line

add the following:

```
<activity android:name=".WebViewActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"/>
```

7. If you use `webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);` it will lead to a warning that **setJavaScriptEnabled** can introduce XSS vulnerabilities into your application, so review **carefully**! Or you can simply remove it if you don't want to use JS in your webview.

---

***UPDATE***

The final working codes look like the following:

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void goToGoogle (View view) {
        goToUrl ( "http://www.google.com/");
    }

    private void goToUrl (String url) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, WebViewActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("url", url);
        intent.putExtra("name", "Your Title Name");
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

**WebViewActivity.java**

```
package example_company.test_2;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_view);

        Intent i = getIntent();
        String url= i.getStringExtra("url");
        WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        assert url != null;
        webView.loadUrl(url);

        TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.name);
        textView.setText(i.getStringExtra("name"));
        textView.setOnClickListener(v -> finish());

        ImageButton imageButton = findViewById(R.id.backbtn);
        imageButton.setOnClickListener(v -> finish());
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="example_company.test_2.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:text="CONNECT"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:onClick="goToGoogle"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**webview.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".WebViewActivity">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:theme="@style/Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:popupTheme="@style/MenuStyle">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/backbtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_arrow_back_black_24dp"
            android:contentDescription="Back"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>


    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="example_company.test_2">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".WebViewActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"/>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: perfect ans @pleft +1

Comment: Thanks @pleft for your answer. Just some questions: Should I write the webviewactivity class inside MainActivity.java file !? If so, it gives some errors: (1) webview was unknown, which I imported the webkit. (2) cannot resolve symbol context. (3) class webviewactivity is public, should be declared in a file named webviewactivity.java

Comment: @Omid1989 create a new activity **`webviewactivity`**

Comment: @Omid1989 Quoting from the answer: "3) Create the WebViewActivity class". So create a new file WebViewActivity.java and paste the code there

Comment: @pleft thanks again for your comment. OK, that's done. Only this error remained: cannot resolve symbol context

Comment: Oh, replace with `this`. I will update the answer too

Comment: Dear @pleft, are you sure all the codes are correct? Because again, when I click on CONNECT button, the app goes to background and doesn't launch the website. The normal website activity was solved by adnanul's answer to open in chrome. But now after changing the codes, again I have the same problem. What's wrong ?

Comment: Did you follow all the steps? last step (5) is to change `android:onClick="goToGoogle (MainActivity)"` to `android:onClick="goToGoogle"`. Also check your `logcat` and post any errors or exceptions.

Comment: @pleft yes I followed all the steps including step 5.

Comment: Ok, good, have you corrected the typo here: `String url= i.getStringExtra("url"));`? Just now spotted it, it has one more parenthesis `)` in the end, it is unneeded so remove it please. `String url= i.getStringExtra("url");` I will update the answer too.

Comment: And please post any errors from your `logcat` I have asked you twice and you neglect it, it is very important to check the logcat for errors

Comment: @pleft Mabe there are any other changea to the manifest file according to webview ? Should I remove the `<data android:scheme="http" android:host="www.google.com" />` line ?

Comment: I dont know what this line does. Anyway, please post the errors

Comment: @pleft Here are the logs: `E/OpenGLRenderer: allen debug liyu Key: 103084458052` , `E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main` , `Process: example_company.test_2, PID: 11239` , `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick`

Comment: @pleft I added the full error log of logcat to the main topic above. (Because they didn't fit in comments.)

Comment: ` Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {example_company.test_2/example_company.test_2.WebViewActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?` It is self explaining, add the new activity in your manifest, i will update my answer

Comment: Please check step 6

Comment: Thanks @pleft for your answer. Yes this solved the problem. But one thing remains: it opens the website automatically in chrome. What should I do to open the website inside the app ?

Comment: @pleft I solved this issue. Adding `webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());` before `webView.loadUrl(url);` and also adding `import android.webkit.WebViewClient;` to `WebViewActivity.java` class solvde the problem.

Comment: @pleft I'm editing your answer to add the final working codes.

Answer (score 2):

In Manifest , add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

& In `activity_main.xml`Change `android:onClick="goToGoogle (MainActivity)"` to `android:onClick="goToGoogle"`

Thanks

Comment: Thanks @adnanul for your answer. This solved the problem of app getting minimized. But it opens the web page in chrome. I need to open the page inside the app.

Comment: @Omid1989 this link may be helpful. thanks https://www.androidhive.info/2016/12/android-working-with-webview-building-a-simple-in-app-browser/

Answer (score 1):

Two solutions for this -

Change `android:onClick="goToGoogle (MainActivity)"` to `android:onClick="goToGoogle"`

Or

Attached a click listener on your button programatically

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            goToGoogle(view);
        }
    });
```

You can also use webview in your layout and load the website inside that webview

Comment: he has done, via the `android:onClick` in the xml layout.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method
>   goToGoogle(MainActivty)(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for
>   android:onClick attribute defined on view class
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'button'

The onclick is expecting a override method and you are passing different arguement.

Change you onClick from

```
 android:onClick="goToGoogle (MainActivity)"
```

to

```
android:onClick="goToGoogle"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code, It will help you to open. Its Work for me.

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

 @Override
 public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
   view.loadUrl(url);
  return true;
 }
});
```

you can also try this way:

```
 webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
 webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
 webView.loadUrl("Your URL goes here");
```

[[image]android](/questions/tagged/android) [webviewcontrol](/questions/tagged/webviewcontrol) [app](/questions/tagged/app)